# C# zip library which is legacy (ZIP 2.0) compression compatible

Tags: c#, .net

Is anyone aware of a C# zip library which is legacy (ZIP 2.0) compression compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried DotNetZip?

http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Comment: actually just looking at it. Does it do: legacy (ZIP 2.0) compression?

Comment: Not sure. But if you try it and it works, there's your answer.

Comment: This helped. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420302/get-kmz-file-from-controller alternat. you can use gzOs.UseZip64 in the original code.

Answer (score 1):

I used and still use this one (SharpZipLib): http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/

Comment: Thanks. Which of their compression modes: Stored, Deflated, Deflate64, BZip2, WinZipAES is the one I am looking for? The last two are not supported. My question is related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420302/get-kmz-file-from-controller

Answer (score 0):

[Using the Zip Classes in the J# Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164129.aspx)